# How update submodules temporary local?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have application and library. Library is a submodule 'mounted' to subdirectory of application.
I am heavily modifying library. I am using application to test library.
Each commit I have to push to Github (or other) and update the submodule for the application.
If is possible (temporary) to use local submodule with many commits?, even I want use submodule branches. I only want to push commits to remote submodule once in a while.